# How do I remove the same characters of a file name for many files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, rename

How do I remove the same characters of a file name for many files in folder in Windows 7

For Example: file name is 123456789abcdefghij.pdf how can i remove characters 
abcdefghij

Comment: Get filenames list text file using DIR /B. Import it to Excel into column A. Build rename command by formula using string functions (CONCAT, REPLACE, maybe plus some another) in column B. Copy column B and paste it into CMD window.

Comment: Use this software....https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Comment: @Mohammed you are welcome, that software has saved me so much time with 100's of thousands of files.

Comment: You received some answers, and apparently a useful comment, but the question is very ambiguous and can be interpreted in endless ways.  Are there multiple files with "abcdefghij" in precisely the same location?  In different locations?  Is it actually that character string or are those placeholders for various strings in that location?  Without clarification, answers will be confusing to other readers with related problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell for tasks like this.

```
Get-Item .\*.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -replace "\D+","") + $_.Extension }
```

The command `Get-Item .\*.pdf` [gets all PDF files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-3.0) in the current directory and [passes them](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-3.0) one by one to the [`Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-3.0) command (no need for a Foreach loop).

In `$_.BaseName -replace "\D+",""` we use a simple [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to remove every non numeric characters (`\D+`) from the filename but not from the extension. The output of the `{...}` code block is the input of the `-NewName` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

We can try to use Windows PowerShell tool.

The full command:

**get-childitem *.pdf | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("abcdefghij", "") }**

Analyze the command:

**get-childitem *.pdf**

This lists all files whose names end with **.pdf**.  They are then piped to the next command with the **|** operator.

**foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("abcdefghij", "") }**

This replaces all instances of **abcdefghij** with nothing, denoted by **""**, effectively wiping the word from all the files in the directory.

We can also modify **get-childitem *.pdf** to **get-childitem** – that would rename all the files in the directory, not just files whose names end with **.pdf**.